# How to get the traffic between pods in Kubernetes

Tags: networking, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

There are already tools out there which visualize the traffic between pods. In detail the state the following:

- [Linkerd tap](https://linkerd.io/2/reference/cli/tap/) listens to a traffic stream for a resource.
- In [Weave Scope](https://github.com/weaveworks/scope), edges indicate **TCP connections** between nodes.

[image: Linkerd tap]

I am now wondering how these tools get the data because the Kubernetes API itself does not provide this information. I know that Linkered installs a proxy next to each service but is this the only option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component that monitors the traffic must be either a sidecar container in each pod or a daemon on each node. For example:

- Linkerd uses a sidecar container
- Weave Scope uses a DaemonSet to install an agent on each node of the cluster

A sidecar container observes traffic to/from its pod. A node daemon observes traffic to/from all the pods on the node.

In Kubernetes, each pod has its own unique IP address, so these components basically check the source and destination IP addresses of the network traffic.

In general, any traffic from/to/between pods has nothing to do with the Kubernetes API and to monitor it, basically the same principles as in non-Kubernetes environments apply.

Comment: So each of this solutions (Sidecar, DaemonSet) observe every pod and match the outgoing and incoming requests?

Comment: A sidecar container observes traffic to/from its pod. A node daemon observes traffic to/from all the pods on the node.

Comment: In Kubernetes, each pod has its own unique IP address, so they basically check the source and destination IP addresses of the network traffic.

Comment: Can you please add your last two comments to your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SideCar Proxy for it or use prometheus-operator which internally uses grafana dashboards. in there you can monitor each and everything.

Comment: Same as @wolmi's answer.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to use [istio.io](https://istio.io) that injects an [envoy](https://www.envoyproxy.io/) proxy as a sidecar container on each pod, then you can use [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io) to scrape metrics from these proxies and use [Grafana](https://grafana.com) for visualisation.

Comment: That would be an option but Weave Scope for example does not need Istio and can still show the connections. Therefore I find it interesting how they or any other comparable tool tackle this problem.

Comment: If your software doesn't have any kind of monitoring or exposing mechanism like exporters, you always need a proxy, in the case of intra pod communication, the proxy has to be inside the pod to control the ingress traffic and allow you to have the metrics. With that in mind, each solution makes a different implementation based on the same idea.